# Bottom sheet view not able to expand completely after google material lib update?

Tags: android, androidx, bottom-sheet

Earlier I was using the **alpha 03** lib in which I was able to expand the bottom sheet view when the app is launched .

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'

After an update to  **alpha 04** .I found out the code I was using earlier 
 is not working and only partial view is visible .

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'

But after swipping up and down the view is perfectly expanded.

How to make sure that the bottom sheet is view completely when it is launched for first time. Was the earlier code incorrect?

This is the code that's in MainActivity

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetSummaryLayout);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(false);
```

xml code for the bottom sheet view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_summary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    tool:behavior_peekHeight="300dp">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="321dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent_gradient"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/summary_card_left_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/summary_card_left_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/summary_card_right_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/summary_card_right_padding" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_summary_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf I have a bottom sheet view that is partially visible  when i launch app . The behaviour is happening only in alpha 4 and alpha 5 . its working perfectly in alpha 3

Comment: You've got two peek heights, why? Remove one with the tool and see if it helps.
    `app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    tool:behavior_peekHeight="300dp">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code, I have used in my one of project, you may get help

```
  public class PopUpFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @NonNull @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

                bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int i) {

                        switch (i){

                            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {
                        setScrim(v);

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Do something with your dialog like setContentView() or whatever
        return dialog;
    }
    private void setScrim(float slideOffset) {
       // bottomSheet.getForeground().setAlpha((int) (slideOffset * 150));


    }

 public static PopUpFragment newInstance() {

        PopUpFragment fragment = new PopUpFragment();

        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layou, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

}
```

**To show BottomSheet**

```
  PopUpFragment bottomDialogFragment =
                PopUpFragment.newInstance();

        bottomDialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(),"PopUpFragment");
```

Comment: This thing is not working in alpha 04 and alpha 05. the view becomes partially visible when launched its not completely expanded

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this library in production or app deployed on Play store? I'd suggest you use only stable releases of any library unless the alpha features are *very* much needed.

Also, whenever you use any other releases other than the stable release library, do keep an eye on the issue tracker for its Github repo for issues and possible workarounds.

Here's the Github [changelog](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) for every version of [Material Components Android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) repo. You should read the changelog and decide whether you want to get those alpha features at the risk of instability or listed issues or not.

Also, there's a comparison page included on the Github repo where you can compare the changes of any two versions. See this page [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/compare/1.1.0-alpha03...1.1.0-alpha04).

The second line of the comparison table mentions changes to setHideable's behaviour. Read more [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/267bca1fd20bc9c07e45fd8089a35c4f6016d65f).

> setHideable(false) on hidden bottom sheet animates to collapsed state

Remove setHideable() and see if it works as intended.

Comment: this is not working . its still showing the partial view when launched

Comment: Issue resolved ,My Coordinator Layout  was having match parent height and there was no layout gravity mentioned .